# How to move a child node under another child?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I've researched and tried some of the suggestions on stack overflow, but the code doesn't seem to be working.  I've been trying to move a node, by copying and then deleting the node, but everything ends up getting deleted in firebase (original and copied post).

Goal: move the data from under the child "pending" to child "post" after the user hits a button.

I want to move Shelly A. pending post under post.

Firebase database:

```
-pending
  -childByAutoId()
    -name: Shelly A.
    -post: "Haha"

-posts
  -childByAutoId()
    -name: Josh A.
    -post: "funny"
```

Code

```
ref = Database.database().reference()

//copying the node from the child "pending" to child "posts"
self.ref.child("pending").child(event.id!).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                self.ref.child("posts").child(event.id!).setValue(snapshot.value)

            })
        //deleting the original posts
            self.ref.child("pending").child(event.id!).setValue(nil)
```

Watching the database, I'm able to get the data copied, but a split second later, the new copied data gets completely deleted with the old post.  Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see a change being made briefly before being rolled back, most commonly this happens because you have a [security rule](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) that rejects the change.

In that case, the client first fires the local events for the change, then sends the change to the server. Then when it hears back from the server that the change was rejected, it fires local events to get the state correct again.

So it sounds like in your case you **are** allowed to delete the node from `pending`, but not allowed to add the data under `posts`.

---

A good way to prevent this type of partial operation is to include both the delete and the write in a single, multi-location update operation.

```
ref = Database.database().reference()

self.ref.child("pending").child(event.id!).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    var updates = [
        "posts/\(event.id!)": snapshot.value,
        "pending/\(event.id!)": nil
    ]
    self.ref. updateChildValues(updates)
})
```

With this code, both the write of the new node, and deleting the old node are sent to the database as one operation, so also get accepted or rejected by your security rules as one.