# How to move a child in firebase with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rVma.png)
I want to move userCart child to ordertest.

Comment: There is no API to move or rename a node. You will have to 1. Read the node from its old location, 2. Write it to the new location, 3. Delete it from the old location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API to move or rename a node. You will have to

1. Read the node from its old location,
2. Write it to the new location,
3. Delete it from the old location.

If atomicity is important, you can combine #2 and #3 in a single multi-path write operation by setting the old location to `null` (which is an alternative way to delete a node).

Also see:

- [Change keys in Firebase Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68788173/change-keys-in-firebase-realtime-database/68788193#68788193)
- [How to move a child node under another child?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60942884/how-to-move-a-child-node-under-another-child/60943001#60943001)
- [Move data in Firebase Realtime Database on Android (copy and then delete)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55185564/move-data-in-firebase-realtime-database-on-android-copy-and-then-delete/55187444#55187444)